# how to pass a param to socket chat client through browser url

Tags: node.js, sockets, parameters

I just created a small socket.io chat and my server code is like

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.broadcast.emit('Welcome to Dobuyme');
});

http.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:' + port);
});
```

An my client side in the index.html is

```
 $(function () {
        var socket = io();
        $('form').submit(function(){
          socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
          $('#m').val('');
          return false;
        });
        socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
          $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
          window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
        });
      });
```

Now i can connect the chat server through the url

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

Now i want to integrate this module with my program, for that i need to pass a user id to this url.i just did something like

```
http://localhost:3000/index.html?id=2
```

But i cant pass the id.How can pass an id variable to node server through the url